# C++ Редактор с подсветкой синтаксиса, автотабуляций и intellisense для ubuntu

Tags: c++

Добрый вечер. Столкнулся с проблемой написания кода на ubuntu. Интересует есть ли редактор с перечисленными выше требованиями и минималистичным интерфесом и желательно для работы с командной строки. До этого работал с под винды, пользовался студией. По роду деятельности пришлось перейти на linux и g++ компилятор. Искал редактор, но ничего хорошего не нашел. В интернете предлагают, либо полноценную среду разработки, либо как вариант vim. Сейчас работаю как раз через vim, но что очень сильно раздражает. Плохая автотабуляция, которую надо подключать каждый раз при вызове редактора(может настройки можно как то сохранять, но я не разобрался ещё как), Некоректная подсветка по которой не понятно, где у тебя что, и отсутствие автодополнения или хотя бы каких то обозначений граматических ошибок. Упустил запятую или букву в слове, и видишь это только при компиляции. Посоветуйте как выйти из данной ситуации, и какой есть аналог.

Comment: Могу предложить попробовать QtCreator.

Comment: Vim очень мощный редактор , благодаря  плагинам, можно настроить все. Если есть интерес я могу предоставить свои настройки vim редактора

Comment: требования  "intellisense для C++" и "легкий редактор, а не полноценная среда разработки" противоречат друг другу. Для приемлемого уровня подсказок надо, как минимум, знать набор путей поиска заголовочных файлов и опции компилятора (с++11 или нет, и т.д.). Возьмите QtCreator.

Comment: если не сложно, хотелось бы взглянуть на настройки vim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря `libclang` на данный момент в знаменитой
двойке редакторов `vim` и `emacs` можно получить автодополнение,
переход к определению символа, простые рефакторинги и т.д. и т.п.
Т.е. вполне на уровне современных `IDE`:

1. Для vim: https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe
2. Для emacs: https://github.com/Andersbakken/rtags

Но ИМХО, если есть проблемы с тем чтобы прописать нужные
команды в `~/.vimrc` и приходится их вводить каждый раз при запуске,
то стоит посмотреть в сторону `IDE` где все уже настроено и работает,
типа `CLion`.

Comment: ...или взять готовый конфиг, хотя минимально настраивать придётся даже его: [вот слой C/C++ в Spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Blang/c-c%2B%2B).